What is the part number for the marking code AEW0 or EW0?
I couldn't find a part number for the marking code AEW0 of this integrated circuit. From the picture, I'm not sure if it starts with AEW0 or EW0.
Could you please help me identify the possible part numbers for this marking code as shown in the image?



Could you add details about what the circuit does - and an overview of the surrounding circuitry.

This component is connected to the resistor at the bottom of the LT3741 feedback, which seems to me that its output is always at a low level, one of the pins of this component goes to a microcontroller that has a pull up resistor.
